# HTML5 how to know if an Image contains a drawable image?

Tags: html, canvas

For HTML5 Image object, is there a way to know if it contains a drawable bitmap?

For example I use the following code:

```
var img = new Image();
```

Clearly the Image is not drawable at this point because no src is binded to it. Now if you call:

```
img.src = "www.blabla.."
```

Before the image is loaded, the Image is also not drawable, so my question is if there is a way to know if a Image object is drawable? BTW, without using onload function.

I am not sure if this question is clear. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could test img.src

```
if(img.src){
   //drawable
}
```

You can also query the complete property of the image
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_img_complete.asp

Comment: img.src will always become set before the image is drawable so this doesn't work.

Comment: The complete property is what I want. Thank you!